# Python df.to_csv only prints last line even if for loop is present

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am writing a code where the final results(denoted by x) to be exported to csv file. I used a for loop to iterate over but stil it only exports the last line of the result. My full code below is:

```
import csv
import itertools
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


domainfile=open('domainsinfo.csv',newline='',encoding='utf_8')
reader=csv.reader(domainfile)
w=[]
  for row in reader:
    w.extend(row)

domain = list(itertools.permutations(w,1))
print(domain)

 def url_report(domain):
    url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report'
    params = {'apikey': '', 'resource':domain}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return response

def pp_json(json_thing, sort=True, indents=4):
        if type(json_thing) is str:
            print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_thing), sort_keys=sort, 
    indent=indents))
      else:
              print(json.dumps(json_thing, sort_keys=sort, 
 indent=indents))
      return None


for d in domain:
    response = url_report(d)
    json_response = response.json()
    pretty_json = pp_json(json_response)

    response_list=[]
    for key in json_response['scans']:   

        if json_response['scans'][key] ['detected'] is True:      
            response_list.append(True)
        else:
            response_list.append(False)
    x=any(response_list)
    print(x)


    for d in domain:        
      final_list=[]

    final_list.append(x)
    result=(final_list)
    result_table = {'Domain': [d], 'Result':result}

    df=pd.DataFrame(data=result_table) 
    print(df)

    export_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\csv', index=None, header=True)

print(pretty_json)


input()
```

Can someone explain why this does not work even if the for loop is present

Comment: I suggest, to get the indentation right; too many assumptions are required right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like liakoyras mentioned, you are writing your dataframe in the CSV. There are many ways to overcome your problem. While he suggested a merge, I am giving you another alternative here using [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html). Read the documentation for more information.

Here is how you need to modify your code block, explanation in comments inside the code:

```
######## Declare a dataframe outside the loop
final = pd.DataFrame()

for d in domain:
    ........................
       your other codes
    ........................
    result_table = {'Domain': [d], 'Result':result}

    df=pd.DataFrame(data=result_table) 

    ###### keep appending df to final 
    ###### the final df now gets updated in every loop
    final = final.append(df)

#### now outside the loop, write final dataframe to your csv
final.to_csv('your/path/file.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ankur Sinha & liakoyras

Comment: This code does not seem to save data into the csv file. Could any of you tell as to the reason

Comment: What do you see in the CSV file? This should be working, I use this extensively. May be check if you are getting your data into df first, and if you have final declared outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because in each loop, your .csv is overwritten by your next one.
The df.to_csv exports the df in a csv file.
You could try taking this code out of the loop, or changing the file name dynamically (depending on what you want.

Comment: But in your code, you create a new df for each d in domain, so if you want all of them to be on the same csv, you need a slightly different approach.

Comment: I want all of the domaiins in one csv. So how is the approach then?

Comment: Initialize df at the beginning of your code (`df = pd.DataFrame`) and when you calculate the result table, use `df1=pd.DataFrame(data=result_table)` and then use `df.merge(df1)` in order to concat the two dataframes.

Comment: @ liakoyras if please could you explain this in detail please

Comment: In each loop, you create a new `DataFrame` in the line `df=pd.DataFrame(data=result_table)`. So, the things you have found so far (stored in `df` variable) are overwritten each time. I suggested you change this by creating the `df = pd.DataFrame()` outside the for loop, and use `df.merge` in order to append your new data to df. Then, after the for loop ends, use `df.to_csv` in order to export.

Comment: so what is the real purpose of using df.merge

Comment: Merging the dataframe you want to store all domains with the dataframe you create from each domain. Most definitely this could be done another way, but that was the first thing that popped into my head in order for your code to change as little as possible.

Comment: @ liakoyras: TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'dict'> was passed when I tried to add  
        df1=df.merge(result_table)

Comment: Yes, convert the result table to a dataframe like you do in your code (`df1=pd.DataFrame(data=result_table)`) and then merge the two dfs with `df.merge(df1)` as I said on a previous comment.